# @Violate in a new android studio does not exist in android-studio-2020.3.1.14

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, android-room

Hi everyone today I try to use the room database but I can't because of @Violate annotation, not fount.
even I can't build my own database with databaseBuilder , I got Unresolved reference: java  error
for  PersonDatabase::class.java

```
@Database(entities = [person::class],version = 1,exportSchema = false)
abstract class PersonDatabase:RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun personDao():PersonDao

    companion object {

        private var INSTANCE: PersonDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): PersonDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    PersonDatabase::class.java,
                    "word_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 not added automatically in a project I just add this libray to gradle and then fix my problem.

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.32"